# Android String.equals doesn't work when I trying to match from httpresponse

Tags: android

```
RestClient.post("auth/login/", loginparam, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            String.valueOf(s.toLowerCase().equals("ok")), 
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (s.equals("ok")) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplication(), HomeActivity.class));
        }
    }
});
```

This is the code I used for login in android app, In the Toast text, I can see the server did returned "ok", but s.equals always failed in my case, can someone explain that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try ignore case, like this:

```
if( s.compareToIgnoreCase("ok") == 0) {
   startActivity...
```

Comment: I have found the reason, actually server returned "\""ok"\"" , can you suggest a way to validate a user has logged in? I don't like the way I'm doing.

Comment: That's funny, I didn't think of that!  Sorry, I haven't got a better idea.